# JPA - Execute query against specific database user

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am developing a JAX-RS (Resteasy) application using Hibernate as JPA. The back-end database is Oracle. Currently I've defined an Oracle Datasource in WildFly and JPA queries are executed against the Oracle user configured in data source.

Now I've to implement security around the web api. For this I am going to use JWT tokens. The `App_Users` table in my Oracle database contains the users (please note that these users are actually defined as Oracle database users).

There are two requirements here:

1. When a user sends his login credentials, before generating the JWT
   for the user, I have to validate the credentials against the oracle
   database.
2. When a user sends post/put request, for the audit purposes I want to execute 
   the insert/update query against the user who is sending the data not the
   one who is configured in the WildFly data source.

Can I achieve the above two requirements with Hibernate JPA?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a `DataSource` provided by Wildfly I don't think you'll be able to dynamically change the Oracle user per transaction. This is part of the application server configuration for a JNDI provided `DataSource`.

I would recommend creating an Oracle user with the minimum set of privileges for use by your application at runtime. I would then implement auditing within the application itself rather than at the database level.

Comment: The problem is I can't add audit functionality in the app as it's already implemented at database level using triggers. It's a legacy database.